# Include doc link and graphics in email form Xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to send emails from an Xpage application. Want to include some type of header graphic or HTML styling, and it must include a doc link.

I started using Ulrich Krause's modification of Tony McGuckin's excellent [SSJS here](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter)

However, I have two issues that I cannot resolve - adding the doc link an and also a graphic.

```
var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
var tmp:String ="A New Location Has Been Created: " + document1.getDocument().getItemValueString("businessUnitName") + ".\n\n" + "Please click this doc link and add any additional approvers ==> ";
emailBean.setSendTo("name@domain.com");
emailBean.setSubject("Lcoations");
emailBean.setSenderEmail("name@domain.com");
emailBean.setSenderName("Locations");
emailBean.setFieldName("Body");
//emailBean.setDocument(document1);
emailBean.addHTML("<table><tr><th>Month</th><th>Savings</th></tr><tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr></table>") 
emailBean.addHTML(tmp);
emailBean.setBannerHTML("<table><tr><th>Month</th><th>Savings</th></tr><tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr></table>");
emailBean.setFooterHTML("<p>Kind regards,<br/>Samantha<br/>0012 3456 789</p>");
emailBean.send();
```

I have commented out the setDocument code as it doesn't work and isn't necessary.

I have an image resource in the db called locations.pgn that I want to include - or I can put it on the web at a url I control.

How do I pass in a doc link? I have computed it, but I just don't now how to add it.

The other method I have tried is a more roll my own.

I have this in a button on the Xpage form:

```
var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
var nteUrl:String = doc.getNotesURL();
var sndTo:String ="name.domain.com";
var sndFrm:String ="ame.domain.com";
var sbj:String ="A New Location Has Been Created: blah blah blah");
var body:String =""A New Location Has Been Created: blah blah blah");

sendEmail(sndTo,sndFrm,sbj,body,doc);
```

And then my function:

```
function sendEmail(sndTo,sndFrm,subject,body,trgDoc) {

    var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
    doc.replaceItemValue("Form","Memo");
    doc.replaceItemValue("Subject",subject);
    doc.replaceItemValue("Principal",sndFrm);
    doc.replaceItemValue("From",sndFrm);
    doc.replaceItemValue("SendTo",sndTo);
    doc.replaceItemValue("DisplaySent",sndTo);
    doc.replaceItemValue("SMTPOriginator",sndTo);
    var memo:NotesRichTextItem = doc.createRichTextItem("Body")
    var urlgif="/locations.png";
    memo.embedObject(NotesEmbeddedObject.EMBED_OBJECT, "",urlgif,null);
    memo.appendText(body);
    memo.appendDocLink(trgDoc);
    doc.send();
  return ;
}
```

This attaches the file as an attachment, not as a picture. Can't find a method to do that.

I am agnostic about which method I use, I just want to get one nailed down and tightened up so I can use it throughout my applications.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You create the email based on HTML with `emailBean.addHTML(... your html ...)`.

Use the syntax

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

to add links and

```
<img src="url" ...>
```

to add images.

Instead of an URL you can code the picture in base64 and include it completely in your html like this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZ
AQAAAADskrjOAAAAfElEQVR42mNgrDrAwFCbHs/A4Gp8EUgIBAKJSUCiVuY+A
wNjqAMDw//T/xsYDK9nMDB4/zAGSkimMTAIbz/DwHDitRwDg1agNQPD0YTyBoZ
L/ncbGHg3swN1WBcD9f4Lb2CoLS8AmufB3sDgehWo2LXRDSjmtRkoG5TCAACQ
1SM9QzyOtAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```